# If I change my research group, can my former supervisor restrict my access to my codes that are written by myself?

Tags: phd, advisor, data, databases

Recently, I quitted my current research group and I will start to work with someone else. I was in my former research group for almost three years and during these three years I wrote more 200,000 lines of codes by myself alone. These codes rest in my former advisor group repository in Github, but I have copies of them locally in my computer. I know and I understand totally that I'm not allowed to use those codes without my former adviser agreement and also he is not allowed to do so without my agreement. Recently, he removed and revoked my access to the codes that are written by myself during these three years. As I said, I don't want to use them without his agreement, but I'm wondering why he restricted my access to something that completely is written by me and from scratch. I have the local backups but it just makes me upset and I'm wondering if he is allowed to remove my access or not?

Comment: "I know and I understand totally that I'm not allowed to use those codes without my former adviser agreement and also he is not allowed to do so without my agreement" - the first part is true, the second part likely is not. How do you "know" this? Also obviously yes he can restrict your access to his lab's repository.

Comment: @BryanKrause Clear mention in university policy

Comment: If the github repositiry is for that advisor group and you have left it. Then it seems reasonable that you no longer have access, otherwise you get access to new work they do which is not correct.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer What's the wording? Any exceptions? Especially regarding ex-students.

Comment: Who owns the copyright on the code you wrote? It depends on any contracts between you and the school, and whether you were paid to write it.

Comment: By not revoking the access, you would still have access to the code of others working on the same repos. In a research environment, probably you have access to your work, but not to the work of others. It is a serious thing, it is about a lot of work of many people, not a shared homework task. In a corporate environment, you would be obligated to delete all copies of the repos on your systems. More clearly, you would not ever get a permission to clone any company work to any non-corporate machines; even asking for that would be risky. Violating this would be a criminal offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any supervisor (including the OP's former supervisor) is free to block access to their resources, even when those resources include code written by the person being block (including former students).

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is answered, I would like to add something more.

The fact that you are being blocked from the github may be more than just the former supervisors right, but also your access to ongoing development.  They may be simply removing you from a repository that they plan to continue to work on and develop, in which case you should not have access to ongoing work in a lab you are no longer part of.